# Can not get .load to load a page on Ajax success

Tags: ajax

I have some ajax code that on success loads a new page.  However I can't seem to get it to work.  I can get a page to open if i use the code below

```
window.location.href = "menu.html";
```

but i can not get it to load a page using the following code.

```
function submitForm() {
$.ajax({type:'POST', 
url: 'http://www.domainname.com/page.php',
data:$('#ContactForm')
.serialize(), 
success: function(response) {
    alert("You will now be redirected."); 
      $("#responsecontainer").load("form.html");
}});

return false;
}
```

I have added an alert which triggers everytime, but i just can not get the form.html to load.

Comment: The code seems correct, can you verify if the code give some error?

Comment: I don't get anything, just nothing happens

Comment: i am using a mobile template so i think this must be the problem, maybe some conflict or something, so i think i will start in a blank structure, its all i can think of